# Restricting Member Access to Multiple Specific Classes

Tags: c#, .net, oop, clr

My PUMP can (inflate) my BALLOON. No problem! But when I try to use my PUMP to (pop) the BALLOON, it really doesn't work very well. I can keep using my PUMP and, eventually, it will (pop) the balloon, but my arm is getting really tired, and I want to (pop) it now. So, instead, I get my POINTY STICK and (pop)! Of course, my POINT STICK is even less effective at (inflate)ing my BALLOON, than the PUMP is at (pop)ing it.

```
Class Balloon
{
    Private int _volume = 0;
    Private bool _popped = false;

    Public Balloon() { }

    //Restrict calling to only a PUMP object
    Internal Inflate()
    {
        if (_popped) return;

        _volume += 1;
        if (volume > 10) this.Pop();
    }

    //Restrict calling to only a POINTY STICK object
    Internal Pop()
    {
        if (!_popped) _popped = true;
    }

    Public string GirlHappiness
    { get
        {
        if (!_popped)
            {
            if (_volume < 3)
                return "......";
            if (_volume < 6)
                return "Ooohhh";                    
            else
                return "Ahhhh! Yay!";
            }
        else
            return "WaAaAaAaHhHhHh";
        }
    }

    Public string BoyHappiness
    { get
        {
        if (!_popped)
            {
            if (_volume < 3)
                return "zzzzzz";
            if (_volume < 6)
                return "zzzzzz";                    
            else
                return "zzzzzz";
            }
        else
            return "Ahahaha YAY!";
        }
    }
}
```

So, is there any way to achieve this? I cannot achieve the desired result via separating assemblies, and the other method I've explored, using reflection and tracing the stack, is unreliable outside of debugging. What to do?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways that pop up in my mind: Use explicit interface implementation or events.

With explicit interfaces, you hide the implementation for those who do not threat the instance 'as is'. Example:

```
    interface IPumpable 
    {
        void Pump();
    }
    interface IPoppable
    {
        void Pop();
    }

    class Balloon :IPumpable, IPoppable
    {
        private void IPumpable.Pump()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }   
        private void IPoppable.Pop()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public static void PopMethod(IPoppable poppable)
    {
        poppable.Pop();
    }
    public static void PumpMethod(IPumpable pumpable)
    {
        pumpable.Pump();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Balloon balloon = new Balloon();

        PumpMethod((IPumpable)balloon);
        PopMethod((IPoppable)balloon);
    }
```

Note that the Pump and Pop implementations can be marked private. They are only visible when you threat the balloon as IPumpable or IPoppable respectively.